# Split a column based on round bracket occurrence

Tags: r, regex, tidyverse, dplyr

My data can be downloaded from here

```
tuesdata <- tidytuesdayR::tt_load(2020, week = 4)
spotify <- tuesdata$spotify_songs
```

I want to have track_name without any () & text inside it.

Expected Output: If my track name is RITMO (Bad Boys For Life), I want it to have only RITMO.

We can have the part in () i.e Bad Boys For Life in this case into a separate column feat. I am trying to this using below, saw 10-20 SO question but could not figure it out.

```
spotify %>%
  extract(., track_name, into = c("track_name2", "feat"), "(\\.+)\\s*(.*)",remove = F)
```

I know there is something wrong with my regex, but not sure how to get the expected output

Adding dput for spotify

```
structure(list(track_id = c("6f807x0ima9a1j3VPbc7VN", "0r7CVbZTWZgbTCYdfa2P31", 
"1z1Hg7Vb0AhHDiEmnDE79l", "75FpbthrwQmzHlBJLuGdC7", "1e8PAfcKUYoKkxPhrHqw4x", 
"7fvUMiyapMsRRxr07cU8Ef"), track_name = c("I Don't Care (with Justin Bieber) - Loud Luxury Remix", 
"Memories - Dillon Francis Remix", "All the Time - Don Diablo Remix", 
"Call You Mine - Keanu Silva Remix", "Someone You Loved - Future Humans Remix", 
"Beautiful People (feat. Khalid) - Jack Wins Remix"), track_artist = c("Ed Sheeran", 
"Maroon 5", "Zara Larsson", "The Chainsmokers", "Lewis Capaldi", 
"Ed Sheeran"), track_popularity = c(66, 67, 70, 60, 69, 67), 
    track_album_id = c("2oCs0DGTsRO98Gh5ZSl2Cx", "63rPSO264uRjW1X5E6cWv6", 
    "1HoSmj2eLcsrR0vE9gThr4", "1nqYsOef1yKKuGOVchbsk6", "7m7vv9wlQ4i0LFuJiE2zsQ", 
    "2yiy9cd2QktrNvWC2EUi0k"), track_album_name = c("I Don't Care (with Justin Bieber) [Loud Luxury Remix]", 
    "Memories (Dillon Francis Remix)", "All the Time (Don Diablo Remix)", 
    "Call You Mine - The Remixes", "Someone You Loved (Future Humans Remix)", 
    "Beautiful People (feat. Khalid) [Jack Wins Remix]"), track_album_release_date = c("2019-06-14", 
    "2019-12-13", "2019-07-05", "2019-07-19", "2019-03-05", "2019-07-11"
    ), playlist_name = c("Pop Remix", "Pop Remix", "Pop Remix", 
    "Pop Remix", "Pop Remix", "Pop Remix"), playlist_id = c("37i9dQZF1DXcZDD7cfEKhW", 
    "37i9dQZF1DXcZDD7cfEKhW", "37i9dQZF1DXcZDD7cfEKhW", "37i9dQZF1DXcZDD7cfEKhW", 
    "37i9dQZF1DXcZDD7cfEKhW", "37i9dQZF1DXcZDD7cfEKhW"), playlist_genre = c("pop", 
    "pop", "pop", "pop", "pop", "pop"), playlist_subgenre = c("dance pop", 
    "dance pop", "dance pop", "dance pop", "dance pop", "dance pop"
    ), danceability = c(0.748, 0.726, 0.675, 0.718, 0.65, 0.675
    ), energy = c(0.916, 0.815, 0.931, 0.93, 0.833, 0.919), key = c(6, 
    11, 1, 7, 1, 8), loudness = c(-2.634, -4.969, -3.432, -3.778, 
    -4.672, -5.385), mode = c(1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1), speechiness = c(0.0583, 
    0.0373, 0.0742, 0.102, 0.0359, 0.127), acousticness = c(0.102, 
    0.0724, 0.0794, 0.0287, 0.0803, 0.0799), instrumentalness = c(0, 
    0.00421, 2.33e-05, 9.43e-06, 0, 0), liveness = c(0.0653, 
    0.357, 0.11, 0.204, 0.0833, 0.143), valence = c(0.518, 0.693, 
    0.613, 0.277, 0.725, 0.585), tempo = c(122.036, 99.972, 124.008, 
    121.956, 123.976, 124.982), duration_ms = c(194754, 162600, 
    176616, 169093, 189052, 163049)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: This is a bit unclear. Try `"^(.*?)(?:\\(([^()]*)\\).*)?$"`. What to do with `I Don't Care (with Justin Bieber) - Loud Luxury Remix` or `Beautiful People (feat. Khalid) - Jack Wins Remix`?

Comment: So, does `"^(.*?)(?:\\(([^()]*)\\).*)?$"` work as expected?

Comment: Not every column has text in brackets (`()`) , what do you want to return in that case. Can you show your expected output for these 6 rows. Probably, remove other columns which are unnecessary for this question.

Comment: @RonakShah, for thsoe cases I just want to return the string as it is displayed. Basically I just want to eliminate everything IF there is starting with this '(' sign

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Sample Data:**

```
    library(dplyr)
    (d <- tribble( ~track_name,
               "RITMO (Bad Boys For Life)",
               "I Don't Care (with Justin Bieber) - Loud Luxury Remix",
               "Vaibhav. Thank you."
))
```

*Extract data using regex pattern.*

```
    library(stringr)

    d %>% mutate(
          is_paran_avail = str_detect(track_name, "\\(") & str_detect(track_name, "\\)"),
          name = if_else(is_paran_avail,
                         str_extract(track_name, pattern = ".+(?=\\()"),
                         track_name)
                )
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Bonus:**
  [Cheat sheet](http://edrub.in/CheatSheets/cheatSheetStringr.pdf) for pattern is always useful.

Also, for text inside parenthesis, you can use *str_locate()* and *str_sub()*
Hope it helps!!!

Comment: This is wrong, because for cases where it doesnt have brackets. its giving NA. for ex: I had a track_name shape of you. for that this gives me NA in name

Comment: @VaibhavSingh As you haven't clarified what you need if we don't have brackets. However, you can use if_else condition inside mutate func to avoid NA and update NA as per your wish.

Comment: I agree, just adding that answer can be complete if you have added this line. I am grateful to you, just adding it here so that you can improve your contribution since you are a new contributor. Great work ! spotify %>%
  mutate(name = str_extract(track_name, pattern  =".+(?=\\()"),
         name=ifelse(is.na(name),track_name,name))

Comment: @VaibhavSingh Updated my answer to incorporate your need. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks, I see what you did there :)

Answer (score 1):

Below code removes only text within parentheses, assuming df has two columns (track_num and track_name) as below

#### Sample Data:

df<-data.frame(matrix(0,2,2))

df[,1]<-c(1,2)

df[,2]<-c("RITMO (Bad Boys For Life)","I Don't Care (with Justin Bieber) - Loud Luxury Remix")

colnames(df)<-c("track_num","track_name")

#### Extracting the required pattern:

- To remove any text with parentheses (including parentheses):

  lapply(df[,2],function(x) str_replace(x, " \(.*\)", ""))
- To remove all text from the start of the parentheses:

  lapply(df[,2],function(x) stri_split(x,fixed = "(")[[1]][1])